# Is it possible to map fn+down and fn+up to page down and page up respectively?

Tags: keyboard

My Thinkpad has a Page Up and Page Down on top of the keyboard. It's too far away IMO.  I'm more used to with pressing Fn+Down if I want to use Pagedown on other keyboards. I wanted to bring this habit on my Thinkpad.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) should take care of you:

> AutoHotkey is a free, open-source utility for Windows. With it, you
>   can:
>
> - Automate almost anything by sending keystrokes and mouse clicks. You can write a mouse or keyboard macro by hand or use the macro recorder.
> - Create hotkeys for keyboard, joystick, and mouse. Virtually any key, button, or combination can become a hotkey.
> - Expand abbreviations as you type them. For example, typing "btw" can automatically produce "by the way".
> - Create custom data-entry forms, user interfaces, and menu bars. See GUI for details.
> - Remap keys and buttons on your keyboard, joystick, and mouse.
> - Respond to signals from hand-held remote controls via the WinLIRC client script.
> - Run existing AutoIt v2 scripts and enhance them with new capabilities.
> - Convert any script into an EXE file that can be run on computers that don't have AutoHotkey installed.